# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar

Tags: spring-boot

I am using STS 3.9 version with using to create starter spring boot project ->Web,jpa,mysql,rest combination.This is When i try to run the spring boot application is shows error ....I tried to change the spring plugin JAR verion to 1.1.0 but still not got changes,i tried to make different projects that also produces the same resuly only...please help me to solve this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/HP%20PC/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromUrlClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
    at com.example.demo2.ExampleSpringBoot2Application.main(ExampleSpringBoot2Application.java:10)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromManifestClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:107)
    ... 16 more
```

when i try to run as without dev-tool jar it show error like ...

```
:: Spring Boot ::             (v2.0.0.M3)

2017-08-17 16:02:09.129  INFO 12256 --- [           main] c.e.demo2.ExampleSpringBoot2Application  : Starting ExampleSpringBoot2Application on LAPTOP-vignesh with PID 12256 (started by HP PC in C:\Users\HP PC\Documents\workspace_140817\ExampleSpringBoot-2)
2017-08-17 16:02:09.132  INFO 12256 --- [           main] c.e.demo2.ExampleSpringBoot2Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-17 16:02:09.192  INFO 12256 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@445629: startup date [Thu Aug 17 16:02:09 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-17 16:02:10.095  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-08-17 16:02:10.128 ERROR 12256 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/plugin/core/support/PluginRegistryFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.hateoas.config.LinkBuilderBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(LinkBuilderBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:57) ~[spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.hateoas.config.HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:100) ~[spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at com.example.demo2.ExampleSpringBoot2Application.main(ExampleSpringBoot2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2017-08-17 16:02:10.129  INFO 12256 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@445629: startup date [Thu Aug 17 16:02:09 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-17 16:02:10.130  WARN 12256 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@445629: startup date [Thu Aug 17 16:02:09 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:433) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1004) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:808) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at com.example.demo2.ExampleSpringBoot2Application.main(ExampleSpringBoot2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]

2017-08-17 16:02:10.131 ERROR 12256 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@445629: startup date [Thu Aug 17 16:02:09 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:420) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:240) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:558) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:952) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:527) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:228) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:959) [spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1035) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:808) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at com.example.demo2.ExampleSpringBoot2Application.main(ExampleSpringBoot2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]

2017-08-17 16:02:10.131  WARN 12256 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:728) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:670) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1507) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:421) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:391) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1191) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:879) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:865) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:851) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at com.example.demo2.ExampleSpringBoot2Application.main(ExampleSpringBoot2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 24):

This is because you might be having one of the jars in your maven cache corrupted, which is actually pointed out by `IllegalStateException`.

**Try removing the corrupted jar from your maven cache and re-build your application.**

In your case **just delete this particular file and rebuild your application.**

```
file:/C:/Users/HP%20PC/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/**spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

For more on this topic please refer to this link : [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9120).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like **spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar** got corrupted. Please delete it from your maven cache and try again.

Go to path where ever it is showing the exception and remove it from that location.

In your case, **C:/Users/HP%20PC/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar**

**spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar** delete this jar from above location and clean your project once and then try to run the application. If this issue got resolved and if you face similar issue with any other jars, please delete those jars as well.

Answer (score 1):

It displays on the console, which is the corrupted jar with its absolute path. 
Just delete the jar.
Then do mvn clean install
It'll work fine.

NB. If multiple jars are corrupted, clean up .m2 dir. then do mvn clean install.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Jar file is corrupt. Is it possible for you to execute this to get the MD5 sum?

```
md5 "/C/Users/HP PC/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar"
```

The correct MD5 sum can be found in [spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar.md5](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar.md5) and should be `4e6325e5ed2c1aa1949313c184d83640`

Answer (score 0):

I hovered on the error with Eclipse IDE and then the quick fix fixed all the error that I was encountering. Didn't delete anything from .m2

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is corrupted.

Download it manually and override the old one.

It should work.