# Hibernate - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
>   read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar
>   file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.14.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar

Comment: Looks like `hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar` is missing from classpath. Adding jar will resolve the issue.

Comment: i have this dependency in pom.xml

Comment: From your question, It is very difficult to understand what are you trying to achieve. Are you creating a jar, war or ear file or  Are you executing it as a standalone java program? It's better to post some code and pom.xml.

Comment: ok. I am trying to create an web project.

Comment: try and delete file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.14.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar and rebuild your project.

please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732879/java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-read-class-path-attribute-from-manife

Answer (score 0):

There might be a chance of corrupted dependancy in your `.m2 repository.` 
Remove the .m2 repository and try to clean and rebuild the project.

Where you can find your .m2?

```
C:\Users\userName\.m2
```

Comment: Do i need to delete the whole .m2?

Comment: @SushovanMallick First, try to remove 6.0.14 and try to clean and rebuild if this does not help then remove whole .m2 repository

Comment: now every thing is ok but i can not deploy the application in the web.

Comment: @SushovanMallick please post your console details

Comment: after launching the application i tried to access the application in web always 404 occurred.

Comment: @SushovanMallick there might be no mapping for requested URL or some other problem with the code. Please share your code for details

Comment: i encountered the problem but couldn't understand what will be the mapping

Comment: @SushovanMallick Let's say user request localhost:8080/user/getUser/1 but there is no code written to handle that particular request so there will be no mapping for the request. Please accept and vote up the answer so that others can know about the solution.