# Error in pom.xml due to ribbon dependency

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, netflix-ribbon

Getting the project build error message

```
Project build error: 
         'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon:
```

This my `pom.xml` file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
            <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
            <artifactId>currency-conversion-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>currency-conversion-service</name>
            <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <!-- <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
                </dependency>  -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nextflix ribbon

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Error is gone but while running the application file i got error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar
"

Comment: refer this for class-path not read problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732879/java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-read-class-path-attribute-from-manife . Try deleting your jar and re-run it

Answer (score 0):

You've got to add the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon` dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId> org.springframework.cloud </groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```